# Asp .net core razor pages urldata

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-routing

In the asp .net razor pages, there is the built in urldata.  I use it to easily read from the url.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/routing/creating-readable-urls-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites

What is the equivalent in asp .net core razor pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions` to the view and use this method:

`var url = Request.GetDisplayUrl()`

This will work for .NET Core. Keep in mind this is only for displaying that URL. If you need different parts of the URL then you must extract them yourself from the Request.

Comment: ok, thanks.  That namespace looks like it is used for creating urls, at least what I am seeing in the Msft docs.  Imagine I have a url of /publicscores/teamgame/12345.  It is the same as /publicscores/teamgame?TournamentId=12345. In the second one, I would get the TournamentId as Request.Query["TournamentId"].  In razor in .net 4.8, I would use urldata[0].  I don't understand what I would do in asp .net core.  any suggestions?

Comment: I kept searching and trying things, and then I figured it out.  I'm testing it out and will post back if I am successful.